# Which is the best way to improve memory usage when you collect a large data set before processing it? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net

When I have to get GBs of data, save it on a collection and process it, I have memory overflows. So instead of:

```
 public class Program
 {
     public IEnumerable<SomeClass> GetObjects()
     {
         var list = new List<SomeClass>();
         while( // get implementation
             list.Add(object);
         }
         return list;
     }

     public void ProcessObjects(IEnumerable<SomeClass> objects)
     {
         foreach(var object in objects)
             // process implementation
     }

     void Main()
     {
         var objects = GetObjects();
         ProcessObjects(objects);
     }
 }
```

I need to:

```
 public class Program
 {
     void ProcessObject(SomeClass object)
     {
         // process implementation
     }

     public void GetAndProcessObjects()
     {
         var list = new List<SomeClass>();
         while( // get implementation
             Process(object);
         }
         return list;
     }

     void Main()
     {
         var objects = GetAndProcessObjects();
     }
 }
```

There is a better way?

Comment: What kind of data is it? A database table, an ascii file, an xml file?

Comment: Do you have to be able to reason about the whole set at once?  That is, can you get a small chunk, process a small chunk and then repeat instead of having the whole thing in memory at once?

Comment: Seconding JP's question, do you need the List< > in the second sample?

Comment: @tuinstoel none of them, it's just geo data.

Comment: @JP that's what I done in the second piece of code

Comment: @Henk no, just an IEnumerable

Comment: @Jader:  That depends entirely on your "get implementation" that is not provided.  You should change your "get implementation" to get the data in chunks, process the chunk, save the chunk and repeat if you can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You ought to leverage C#'s [*iterator blocks*](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) and use the `yield return` statement to do something like this:

```
 public class Program
 {
     public IEnumerable<SomeClass> GetObjects()
     {
         while( // get implementation
             yield return object;
         }
     }

     public void ProcessObjects(IEnumerable<SomeClass> objects)
     {
         foreach(var object in objects)
             // process implementation
     }

     void Main()
     {
         var objects = GetObjects();
         ProcessObjects(objects);
     }
 }
```

This would allow you to stream each object and not keep the entire sequence in memory - you would only need to keep one object in memory at a time.

Comment: Didn't solve my problem. When I do Table.InsertAllOnSubmit(objects), the memory overflow still occurs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034429/how-to-prevent-memory-overflow-when-using-an-ienumerablet

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a List, which requires all the data to be present in memory at once. Use `IEnumerable<T>` and produce the data on demand, or better, use `IQueryable<T>` and have the entire execution of the query deferred until the data are required.

Alternatively, don't keep the data in memory at all, but rather save the data to a database for processing. When processing is complete, then query the database for the results.

Comment: Now I will have to ask how to implement your IQueryable solution.

Comment: Using any of the LINQ providers will return an IQueryable<T>.

Answer (score 3):

```
public IEnumerable<SomeClass> GetObjects()
     {

       foreach( var obj in GetIQueryableObjects
             yield return obj
     }
```

Comment: I think you meant "yield return".

Answer (score 1):

You want to [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)!

Delay processing of your enumeration. Build a method that returns an [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) but only returns one record at a time using the yield statement.

Answer (score 1):

The best methodology in this case would be to Get and Process in chunks. You will have to find out how big a chunk to Get and Process by trial and error. So the code would be something like :

```
public class Program
```

{
     public IEnumerable GetObjects(int anchor, int chunkSize)
     {
         var list = new List();
         while( // get implementation for given anchor and chunkSize
             list.Add(object);
         }
         return list;
     }

```
 public void ProcessObjects(IEnumerable<SomeClass> objects)
 {
     foreach(var object in objects)
         // process implementation
 }

 void Main()
 {
     int chunkSize = 5000;
     int totalSize = //Get Total Number of rows;
     int anchor = //Get first row to process as anchor;
     While (anchor < totalSize)
     (
         var objects = GetObjects(anchor, chunkSize);
         ProcessObjects(objects);
         anchor += chunkSize;
     }
 }
```

}