# How to prevent memory overflow when using an IEnumerable<T> and Linq-To-Sql?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, ienumerable, yield

This question is related to [a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034266)

That's my current code

```
 IEnumerable<Shape> Get()
 {
     while(//get implementation
         yield return new Shape(//...
 }

 void Insert()
 {
       var actual = Get();
       using (var db = new DataClassesDataContext())
       {
           db.Shapes.InsertAllOnSubmit(actual);
           db.SubmitChanges();
       }
 }
```

I'm getting a memory overflow, since the IEnumerable is too big. How do I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [InsertOnSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516(VS.100).aspx) rather than [InsertAllOnSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763476(VS.100).aspx).  And then commit at appropriate intervals, like Erich said.

Or, if you want to do it in batches of e.g. 5, try [Handcraftsman's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034429/how-to-prevent-memory-overflow-when-using-an-ienumerablet-and-linq-to-sql/1034476#answer-1035039) or [dtb's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008785#answer-1008855) solutions for getting IEnumerable's of IEnumerable.  E.g., with dtb's Chunk:

```
   var actual = Get();
   using (var db = new DataClassesDataContext())
   {
       foreach(var batch in actual.Chunk(5))
       {
         db.Shapes.InsertAllOnSubmit(batch);
         db.SubmitChanges();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to break it up into multiple batches.  Create a temporary buffer of `Shape` objects, iterate until you fill it or run out from the enumerator, then do a `InsertBatchOnSubmit`.

Comment: How would I get all elements in groups of 5?

Comment: I understood that InsertBatchOnSubmit would be a InsertAllOnSubmit with less elements

Comment: Earwicker's link has an excellent example. I am not sure that will help you since you are doing deferred execution, though.  You might have to have a List<Shape> and batchSize = 5 outside of a loop. Add items from your enumerator, insert once the count reach the batchSize, and then clear out the previous batch. Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following extension method to break the input into appropriately sized subsets

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> InSetsOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int max)
    {
        List<T> toReturn = new List<T>();
        foreach(var item in source)
        {
            toReturn.Add(item);
            if (toReturn.Count == max)
            {
                yield return toReturn;
                toReturn = new List<T>();
            }
        }
        if (toReturn.Any())
        {
            yield return toReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

then persist the subsets

```
void Insert()
{
    var actual = Get();
    using (var db = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        foreach (var set in actual.InSetsOf(5))
        {
            db.Shapes.InsertAllOnSubmit(set);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

You might also find [this MSDN article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/994e75cb-f651-4a2a-aa4a-39de7fa2fd1b) on InsertOnSubmit() vs InsertAllOnSubmit() to be useful.

Comment: Use toReturn.Clear() rather than toReturn = new List to avoid overhead.  This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008785/c-cleanest-way-to-divide-a-string-array-into-n-instances-n-items-long/1008974#answer-1008855 but a little more explicit.

Comment: Clearing the list instead of creating a new one has the side effect of unexpectedly changing the result that was previously returned, a problem if it had not yet been consumed by the caller. For example:

    Enumerable.Range(1, 100).InSetsOf(5).InSetsOf(5).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.First().First() + "-" + x.Last().Last()));
    
gets 

    1-25
    26-50
    51-75
    76-100

as coded, but 

    21-25
    46-50
    71-75
    96-100

if the list is only cleared. Also, since GroupBy is not used it can lazily return results instead of consuming the entire input first.

Answer (score 1):

For a neat way to get batches of items from an IEnumerable, see this:

[C#: Cleanest way to divide a string array into N instances N items long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008785/c-cleanest-way-to-divide-a-string-array-into-n-instances-n-items-long/1008974#1008974)

Update: No good, that works on arrays. If I have some time later and no one else has provided something, I'll write it up...

Comment: Would that work in his case? He doesn't know the size since he only has an IEnumerable.

Comment: Eric Lippert pointed Erich at the solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008785#answer-1008855). dtb gave a function that takes an IEumearable<T> and returns an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>. Each of the inner IEnumerable<T> has up to (e.g.) 5 elements.